# Is the phrase "a few" an exact synonym of "some" or it implies a fewer number?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, grammar-myths

I have just told by experienced native English author (or seems to be one) that "a few" implies a small number.
When you say "**In a few countries**", this implies 3 or 4 countries, but when you say "**In some countries**", this implies like 50% of all countries, say 100 country.

However, this contradicts with Cambridge dictionary [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/few?q=a%20few), and also this makes "a few" equivalent to "few".
It seems that I need a few opinions to make sure of this, and by the way, as an English learner I believe that the person who invented the phrase "quite a few" should be hanged upside down :).

Comment: If you want to hang the person who invented the phrase "quite a few", there'll be a ***fair few*** more "neologists" joining him up on the scaffold. Such expressions aren't exactly ***few and far between***. Blame Shakespeare, who started it all with his [***We few, we happy few, we band of brothers***.](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/402000.html)

Comment: "Some" certainly does not imply "around 50%". Trying to find exact comparisons between these (often intentionally) vague phrases is a waste of time. Context, and even tone of voice, can be more significant than the choice of the word or phrase.

Comment: By the way (not about your question): "Be" is one verb that never takes "do" for questions, at least in Standard English. Not 'Do the phrase "a few" is exact synonym', but 'Is the phrase "a few" an exact synonym...'

Comment: @FumbleFingers Great now I have to understand "a fair few" and "few and far between" as well :)

Comment: a couple [of sweets] is two, a few [sweets] is usually three or four. a fair few still means scant, but perhaps more relative to the total number. quite a few means a significant (unspecified) number. Some can be more than one and less than all.

Comment: @Costa: You have to remember that in English (probably in *all* languages), imprecise terms like ***some, a few, many*** are particularly favoured in "persuasive" language. Where the speaker deliberately steers his audience into over- or under-estimating the *actual* number in order to reinforce the speaker's primary line of argument. With "plausible deniability", if he can dismiss criticism by saying something like *I only said **a few**, not **a vast number***. By which I mean to say - this is an area where speakers are often effectively ***trying*** to "mislead".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think this is a good point although I am not qualified enough to judge it. You mean that these phrases are made to be imprecise, and it makes a perfect sense to me.  Therefore, because these terms are imprecise in the most contexts I believe, I will find a lot of disagreement between native English speakers which is a possible unhappy end of my question.

Comment: Costa: I feel I have to say you'v *almost* got it! It's not really that native speakers would be likely to disagree on *exactly how many* are implied by any given use of one of these "imprecise quantifiers", because it's not so much a matter of the number itself - more a matter of whether ***in the specific context*** we should think of that number as being "**more** than we might like" or "**less** than we might like". See my comment under David's answer, where the "few" who disagree might feasibly be the same actual number in both examples; all that changes is our ***attitude*** to them.

Answer (score 1):

Grammarly to the contrary not withstanding, when the construction requires an article "a few" means the same as just "few" and implies a relatively small number. Consider:

> In most countries copyright lasts for a set number of years beyond the life of the author, but in a few countries the law is different.

In that example "a few" means a small number. This is emphasized by the contrast with "most".

> In a few cases an article is required.

here again "a few" implies an unspecified but small number.

> I have read poor English a few times.

Here "a few" means "several" and might be a small number or a large number. Indeed it might be *ironic understatement* and mean "many". Context and tone of voice are important in such cases.

"Some" in general is simply indeterminate. It might mean as few as two, and it might be as many as "all but one". Quite possibly the speaker does not know how many it applies to. It does not parti8cualrly imply around 50%.

"Few" does mean a relatively small number, but what is relatively small depends on context.

> Few people contract X disease.

means a relatively small number, but that might be tens of thousands out of a population of tens of millions. It would certainly not be limited to 3 or 5 people in the world or even a single country.

Comment: I'm not too sure about that first sentence. Consider how you'd most naturally interpret these different comments under an ELL answer: 1: ***Few** people would disagree with this Answer*, and 2: ***A few** people would disagree with this Answer*. Obviously the first is *positive*, and the second is *negative*. I'm assuming the presence of the article unquestionably *increases* the value we should ascribe to that "few", but I accept maybe that's not exactly what;s going on.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that the implied number in those two cases is the same, unchanged by the use of "A".  You are of course correct about the negative vs positive sense, which is really one of emphasis, as I see it.

Comment: Yeah - that's the point, isn't it? In practice, we almost certainly *can't know* the "real" number of dissenters being referenced by each of those two comments, and I suppose it's at least *feasible* they both refer to the same value. But if I had to place a bet, I think I'd back the number being higher with ***a few*** than with plain ***few***. We're certainly being contextually *encouraged* to think of the latter as referring to a relatively ***more significant*** minority.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/few-a-few/):

Without the article “a,” **few** emphasizes *a small number* of something.

Adding the article removes the emphasis—**a few** means *some.*

(You can find the same but richer answer on [English Language Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/a-few-vs-few).)

**Quite a few** means *a fairly large number* of people or things ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/quite-a-few)).

This is how the things are used in English; I wouldn't scratch my head too much about *why* and I wouldn't hang anyone because of it.

Comment: So you are saying that my author is wrong, and a few countries do not mean 3 or 4 countries, and it has the "exact" meaning of "some countries".

Comment: Yes. Please, note there is a big difference between "few" and "a few." For non-native speakers, this can be easily confused.